# .NET 3.5 Change object type at runtime

Tags: c#

Is there an easy way of doing this in 3.5 ? I have found something called "dynamic" in .NET 4.0.

I have a class of UI which Inherits from CrestronControlSystem class. There I want to be able define
an unknown type of a Panel which would then be instantiated inside of a method.

I don't want to do Boxing/Unboxing because

a) everyone says it's bad

b) I have to cast object type inside of the ControlSystem where I define and use all my UIs. And at this point I would have to know what each UI is in order to cast it, and I don't want this.

so (XpanelForSmartGraphics)home.UIs[0].UI_IPID if it's an object type with XpanelForSmartGraphics via Boxing/Unboxing.

I have tried quite few things with Generics but can't get it to work the way I want it because Generics do not support Properties...

Code:

```
public class ControlSystem : CrestronControlSystem
{
        ..........
        public Home home = new Home("Home", 1, 1);                                                // this just defines my home object and takes number of rooms and number of UIs as a parameter
        .........
        home.UIs[0].DefineUI(0x03, "xpanel", "Study");                                               // here is where I want to say "this unknow object is now XpanelForSmartGraphics because string parameter = "xpanel"
        .........
        home.UIs[0].myPanel.BooleanInput[1].BoolValue = true;                                   // here is how I want to use it, so no casting.
}

public class UI : CrestronControlSystem
{
        public ??????  myPanel;                                                                      // how would it be defined ?

        .......
        public void DefineUI(ushort id, string type, string location)
        {
            .........
            myPanel = ?????? ;                                                                       // how ? :)
            .........
        }
}
```

Thanks

### edit

so this is kind of what I need but I want to be able to call members
of XpanelForSmartGraphics "normal way" thorugh dot operator. This still
behaves as object :

```
public void DefineUI(ushort id, string type, string location)
{
    if (type == "xpanel")
    {
        Type panelType = typeof(XpanelForSmartGraphics);
        this.myPanel = Activator.CreateInstance(panelType);
    }
}
```

so I can't call it this way from ControlSystem class :

```
home.UIs[0].myPanel.BooleanInput[1].BoolValue = true;
```

where BooleanInput[1].BoolValue it's just a property of XpanelForSmartGraphics

Thanks

Comment: Baxing/Unboxing is not bad. It can be bad only when you must microoptimalize some part of code.

Comment: `everyone says it's bad` everybody is wrong apparently ...

Comment: Boxing/Unboxing is something that affects only values types, so it's not your case. Also, it's not related at all with the cast issue you mention at b).

Comment: if it's not related to cast issue I mention how do I use it inside of a ControlSystem without casting (so knowing what I need to cast before I cast it?)

Comment: roughly speaking, box refer to wrap a value type inside an object ([from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)).
Nothing to do with casting, which is a way to tell the compiler "Consider this variabile as an instance of this type, trust me, I know it is" (if it's not, you get an InvalidCastException at runtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create instance dynamicaly with [Activator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator(v=vs.90).aspx) class. The [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.90).aspx) method need the [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.90).aspx) of the created instance.

The Type can be provided by hardcoded way:

```
if (type == "xpanel") { return typeof(MyXPanel); }
```

Or you can provide type dynamicaly by [Type.GetType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.90).aspx) method.

Your can can look like this:

```
public class UI : CrestronControlSystem {
    public object myPanel;

    public void DefineUI(ushort id, string type, string location) {
        Type panelType = Type.GetType(type);
        this.myPanel = Activator.CreateInstance(panelType);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this doesn't work : Type panelType = Type.GetType(type);

Comment: public void DefineUI(ushort id, string type, string location)
        {


            if (type == "xpanel")
            {
                Type panelType = typeof(XpanelForSmartGraphics);
                this.myPanel = Activator.CreateInstance(panelType);
            }
        }

Comment: it's still an object type and I can not use it as if it was XpanelForSmartGraphics

Comment: so if I do this inside of a ControlSystem class : home.UIs[0].myPanel. it will not list me all XpanelForSmartGraphics related fields....

Comment: Thats because, you use the instance through interface of "object" type. You must cast it to the right type - i.e. ((XpanelForSmartGraphics)myPanel).MyProperty.

Comment: Maybe, you need interface for your custom controls? Something linke "IMySpecialControl" and then you can create instances of different classes which all implements interface "IMySpecialControl".